# Talend open studio : tFileInoutXml

Tags: talend

I need the appropriate xpath to read this data in talend open studio
can any body help me?
am trying to read it in tFileInputXml component but withe this xpath :"TABLES/TABLE[@attrname=BTS]/ROWDATA" BUT IT GIVE GIVES ME NULL?!
WHAT IS THE APPROPRIATE XPATH FOR EXTRACTING THIS DATA?

am trying to read it in tFileInputXml component but withe this xpath :"TABLES/TABLE[@attrname=BTS]/ROWDATA" BUT IT GIVE GIVES ME NULL?!

WHAT IS THE APPROPRIATE XPATH FOR EXTRACTING THIS DATA?
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72kcy.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh4fe.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qhTj.jpg)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also don't YELL AT US.